# Traducción de "Commute": Ir diariamente de casa al trabajo y viceversa

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

¿Existe en español algún término con el significado de `viajar diariamente de casa al trabajo (o del trabajo hasta casa)`?

En inglés existe el término `Commute`, tiene el significado de

> to travel back and forth regularly (as between a suburb and a city)
>
> Fuente: [Diccionario Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commute)

O también

> (intr) to travel some distance **regularly** between one's home and one's place of **work**
>
> Fuente: [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/commute)

En Español suele usarse la fórmula "camino del trabajo/ camino a casa", pero me gustaría saber si existe un término como `commute`.

> I had a two-hour commute today due to the traffic  <sub>Me ha costado dos horas llegar al trabajo (o a casa) por culpa del tráfico</sub>
>
> I read during my commute <sub>Leo durante mi viaje a casa/al trabajo</sub>
>
> I work from home, so I can say good bye to that horrible communte <sub>Ahora trabajo desde casa, así que ahora puedo decirle adiós a esos horribles viajes de ida y vuelta al trabajo</sub>
>
> My commute is easier on the way home <sub>Mi viaje de vuelta a casa desde el trabajo es más fácil que el de camino al trabajo</sub>

Soy consciente de que la traducción formal de "commute" sería ["migración pendular"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migraci%C3%B3n_pendular), pero creo que es un término que nadie usaría realmente para describir la acción.

> Uf, mi *migración pendular* me ha llevado dos horas hoy por el tráfico.
>
> *Migro pendularmente* cogiendo el 88 y luego la línea roja.

¿Existe algún otro término más "dulce" para el oído que describa la acción de viajar diariamente del trabajo a casa o viceversa?

Comment: En la vida había oído la expresión "migración pendular". La acabo de aprender ahora mismo.

Comment: Existe la expresión latina ***in itinere*** usado habitualmente para referirse a accidentes. Me parece que es jerga legal y supongo que el diccionario no lo recoge.

Comment: Sí, opino también que la traducción `migración pendular`  no tiene sentido. Yo lo traduciría por **desplazamiento laboral** pero podría dar a entender otra cosa.

Comment: @walen, gracias. Pues he estado casi dos días para publicarla (Con el borrador ahí guardado por la falta de tiempo) y un poco más aún pensándome si era buena pregunta o no. No sabía si le estaba buscando tres pies al gato, o prácticamente respondiendo mi propia pregunta...

Comment: En inglés "**commute**" se usa en el sentido legal de "conmutar una pena o deuda". Recuerdo haber leído que cuando la gente empezó a vivir fuera de la ciudad donde estaba su trabajo y necesitaba usar 2 o más servicios de transporte, entonces le "conmutaban" el valor del segundo servicio pagando un menor valor y así fue como la palabra "commute" adquirió ese otro significado para referirse al trayecto o desplazamiento hogar-trabajo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La RAE me responde a [la pregunta que le he hecho en Twitter](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/889366028114964480) afirmando que [no existe ningún término](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/889751852660776961) en español que exprese por sí solo lo que expresa la voz inglesa *commute*, y [propone expresiones](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/889752575293128704) como "desplazamiento al centro de trabajo".

Por mi parte creo que la expresión que suelo usar es *trayecto de casa al trabajo* o *del trabajo a casa*. En este caso, por contexto se puede sobreentender parte de la expresión, y por tanto se puede hablar de "los trayectos al trabajo" (se entiende que desde casa) o "los trayectos a casa" o "de vuelta a casa" (se entiende que desde el trabajo).

He encontrado en el CREA un par de usos en prensa de esta expresión:

> *Los secuestradores lo detuvieron en una carretera, disfrazados de Carabineros, en el trayecto de su trabajo a su casa; [...].*
>
> Proceso, 07/07/1996 (México).
>
> ---
>
> *Los poseedores de una N-Gage ya pueden encarnar a un audaz agente secreto durante su trayecto al trabajo en el autobús.*
>
> El País. Ciberpaís, 15/04/2004 (España).

Nótese como en este último caso se ha omitido la parte de *desde casa*.

Sobre el uso concreto de la palabra *trayecto* sobre otras como *viaje*, me remito a la definición de trayecto, que no puede ser más simple:

> **[trayecto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aXwbasB)**
>
> Del fr. *trajet*.
>
> 1. m. Espacio que se recorre o puede recorrerse de un punto a otro.
> 2. m. Acción de recorrer un trayecto.

Supongo que el hecho de que los puntos de inicio y partida de dicho espacio recorrido sean siempre los mismos puede favorecer esta expresión. En todo caso, no es la única. Te pongo otros ejemplos (Andalusian mode on):

> I had a two-hour commute today due to the traffic
>   *No veah, quillo, doh horah de atahco hoy de camino al trabaho*
>   [O, si estás en el trabajo:] *Tío, doh horah de atahco pa vení pacá*

Comment: No es mala respuesta, pero creo que "trayecto" a secas depende demasiado del contexto. "Pongo al Fary en _mis trayectos_" no me dice de por sí si son los trayectos al trabajo/casa, al pueblo los fines de semana, o a hacer la compra cada X tiempo (creo yo) y necesita un poco de contexto. Con "commute" es el propio vocablo el que implica el tipo de trayecto (trabajo-casa).

Comment: @Diego te pido disculpas, veo que la respuesta no ha quedado clara. Lógicamente solo la palabra "trayecto" no sirve, hay que acompañarla de "al trabajo" o similar. Lo que quería era enfatizar el uso de "trayecto" por encima de "viaje". Editaré la respuesta cuando pueda.

Comment: No pasa nada. "Trayecto" es una alternativa a las propuestas de la pregunta. A ver qué dice la RAE cuando respondan a ese tweet (tuit?) (Gracias por ponerlo).

Comment: @Diego he añadido pequeños cambios para clarificar la respuesta. Y sobre tu duda, la RAE aceptó la adaptación gráfica [tuit](http://dle.rae.es/?id=asqoMGb) en la última edición del DLE, junto con [tuitear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=asr6h3K). No espero una respuesta pronta, la RAE creo que anda de vacaciones por estas fechas...