# How to translate "Queendom" into Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, palabras-raras, concurso-de-popularidad

Reading a short story during my [commute](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21585/5481), I came across the the word "queendom", as opposed to "kingdom".

I thought it would be an interesting question or exercise to try to translate this word into Spanish, since the Spanish words for king and  queen (*rey* and *reina*, respectively) are so similar that is a challenge to deconstruct "reino" etymologically and reconstruct it in a way that a "queendom" is unambiguously distinguishable from "kingdom".

---

**Update**: Context for this question.

> Once there was a young princess who, when she grew tired of beating her
>   head against the male power structure at her castle, would relax by walking
>   into the woods and sitting beside a small pond [...]
>
> One day, while she was envisioning the utopia that her **queendom** could
>   become if womyn  were  in  the  positions  of  power [...]
>
> <sub>Extract from [Politically Correct Bedtime Stories: Modern Tales for Our Life and Times](https://bbs.pku.edu.cn/attach/85/31/8531ff112a962431/politically%20correct%20bedtime%20stories.pdf), a 1994 book written by American writer James Finn Garner.</sub>

To clarify further, this question tries to put you in the shoes of the translator, having to find a word in Spanish for "queendom", having to preserve the connotations of a *queendom* of being a *queen-centric* and not a *king-centric* (male-centric) form of rulership.

Comment: Por si acaso: [etimología de "reino" en etimologias de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?reino): "reino, territorio que manda un rey, viene del latín _regnum_ =territorio del rey" y en [wikcionario](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/reino): Del castellano antiguo reyno, y este del latín regnum, a su vez de rex, "rey"

Comment: Al parecer [_queendom_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queendom_(TV_series)) fue una serie de tele y no se ha traducido el título al castellano, lo verían complicado :) Hay una [lista de posibles traducciones](https://context.reverso.net/traduccion/ingles-espanol/queendom) que variarían según el contexto. _Divas_ es una que me gusta, pero claro, dependería de cuándo se usa.

Comment: Esta pregunta parece perfecta para el tag [concurso-de-popularidad](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concurso-de-popularidad) que propuse no hace mucho... :-)

Comment: I doubt seriously that this is about monarchy. How about you post the sentence? In gay slang, queen is a term used to refer to a flamboyant or effeminate gay man. The term can either be pejorative or celebrated as a type of self-identification. Wikipedia. And queendom is a made up word.|| Why did you link to the word commute??

Comment: @Lambie Diego read it in a short story, so the context is probably clear and has nothing to do with gay slang but with the domains of a queen. The funny thing is how such a made up word can be adapted into Spanish. The link in "commute" is to a previous question in this site where we tried to translate the word into Spanish.

Comment: @Charlie Pues pensé lo de la etiqueta. Me decido a ponerla ahora porque "queendom" es una palabra inventada (aunque creo que la validez de esta etiqueta debería discutirse en meta un poco más). Espero que el contexto sirva para clarificar el sentido de este término.

Comment: I guess "reinano" by @Charlie is the best suggestion, but I would also point out that in Spanish, such a term is probably less needed, because "reino" does not have a masculine connotation in the way "kingdom" does. The word "reino" sounds as much related to "rey" as to "reina", and that is probably why "reina" - specific words such as "reinano" sound so funny.

Comment: @wimi Fair enough, but then you would miss this joke or remark from the story when translating to Spanish. "Reinano" is a great proposal, although it would need explanation. But again, since "queendom" is an invented word, this might be the best we can have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is

> reinarquía

It's a parody of

> monarquía

It's a little weak because, when heard, the distinction between *rey* and *reina* could be lost; but it comes close to capturing the humour in the original.

Comment: The word _reinarquía_ actually sounds quite cool, it's a nice option, but it's not exactly the word the OP wanted to adapt. Nonetheless, if I were to translate the work into Spanish this would be a good choice, trying to adapt the sentence to use _reinarquía_ instead of _queendom_.

Comment: Brilliant... inspired.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as best answer, even if the other ones also have merit. The word "reinarquía" might not be as closely related to "queendom" as other option, but it is the one that works the best in case we had to use it for the Spanish translation of the book. It is "self sufficient" enough so we don't need to explain what it is, and with the context of the book/story, it would be perfectly understood and convey, as closely as possible, what "queendom" wanted to imply.

Answer (score 3):

Reino. There is no equivalent in Spanish, I would use 'dominios de la reina' or 'terrenos de la reina' or 'estado de la reina', but none of them sound 100% correct

Comment: It is a made-up, nonce word in English....

Comment: I don't see how "dominios de la reina" or "terrenos de la reina" sounds incorrect. It's 100% valid

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely convinced, but given that Spanish *rey* comes from Latin *rex*, which gave *regnum* (Spanish *reino*), then from Latin *regina* (Spanish *reina*) we could have *reginanum* that could give a hypothetical Spanish ***reginano***, or maybe a simplified version such as ***régino***, or even ***reinano***, closer to *reina*.

But none of those words sounds as cool as *queendom*, nor is its meaning evident. Maybe the last one is more evident but sounds terrible to me. Maybe we should try with a synomym for *reina*.

Comment: I think reinano has the best pedigree even if it sounds terrible to you. To be honest queendom does not sound that good to me even ignoring the possibility of confusion due to multiple meaning of queen in English

Comment: @mdewey to me, the problem is that _reinano_ sounds like a mixture of _reinado_ and _enano_.

Comment: @Charlie what about "réinano" with an accent then?

Comment: @wimi I would prefer _régino_ then, it's closer to _reino_, sounds better and does not create confusion, although its etymology is more obscure.

Answer (score 0):

**El dominio de [la] reina**

> Estaba imaginando la utopía que podría llegar a ser el dominio de reina.